# Why does NSNumberFormatter skip a number?

Tags: objective-c, nsnumberformatter

So lets say I have the following:

`NSNumber *num = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:12345678901234567];`

Now I would like for that to be formatted as a string in the following format: `1.234567E16`

I have tried both:

```
    formatter.numberStyle = NSNumberFormatterScientificStyle;
    formatter.maximumFractionDigits = 6;
```

and

```
formatter.positiveFormat = @"0.00000E0";
```

But my result is always `1.23457E16`

Why does it skip the 6?

If I change it to `maximumFractionDigits = 7` it would print `1.234568E16`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Isn't it just because the 6 gets rounded and since the next digit is a 7, it gets rounded to a 7? If you use 1234562, does it still "skip" one?

Comment: Yes it is, a few minutes after posting I tried `formatter.roundingMode = NSNumberFormatterRoundDown;` and that solved the problem. I should probably go to bed.

Comment: @PeterFoti If you found a solution, please post an answer or mark an existing one. Thanks

Comment: How do you want negative numbers to be handled? NSNumberFormatterRoundDown may not do what you want there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's most likely rounding the 6 up to 7.

Answer (score 1):

I do not suggest using `formatter.roundingMode = NSNumberFormatterRoundDown;` since that is a hack.

What you need to do to force 6 digits is set the maximum **and the minimum** number of fractional digits.

```
[formatter setMaximumFractionDigits:6];
[formatter setMinimumFractionDigits:6];
```